# Elastic Search: Multiple term search in one query

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

New to ElasticSearch.

I have documents under an `index`: `myindex` in Elastic search with mappings:
http://host:port/myindex/_mapping

```
{
"mappings":{
   "properties": {
        "en_US":  {
             "type": "keyword"
                  }
                 }
          }
}
```

Let's say my 3 documents look like this:

```
{
"product": "p1",
"subproduct": "p1.1"
}

{
"product": "p1",
"subproduct": "p1.2"
}

{
"product": "p2",
"subproduct": "p2.1"
}
```

Now, I am querying using for single subproduct `p1.1` with product `p1` as below and it's working fine:

POST: http://host:port/myindex/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "product" : "p1" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "subproduct" : "p1.1" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My question is**:
How I can query for 2 or more subproducts in one _search query, like suproducts `p1.1` and `p1.2` under product `p1` ?
Query should return list of all subproduct `p1.1` and subproduct `p1.2` with `p1` product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the `term`-query in your filter-clause to a `terms`-query and search for multiple terms.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "product" : "p1" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms" : { "subproduct" : ["p1.1", "p1.2"] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.

is there a way we can get only one return from each `term` ? 
The term having least number of blanks in it's field should only be selected ?

Comment: No. Your terms contain blanks? You would need to solve such a requirement by using a different query, different analyzers (moving away from exact matches). Please raise a new question for this with a concrete example, as - if I’m not mistaken - comments should not be used for new questions